# How to organize express endpoints properly

Tags: node.js, api, express, endpoint

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to use the `/:variable` notation effectively. In my setup I have this layout.

```
router.route("/").get()
router.route("/:id").get().put().post().delete()
router.route("/auth").get().put().post()
```

When I call `/auth` it fails to go there, instead it triggers the method under the `/:id`. How can I make sure when I say /auth it does not goto that `/:id` path.

Comment: I suggest to change the /:id to something like /login/:id

Comment: I have all these routes under a group `router.use("/user", userRoutes)` so adding a `/login/:id` wont work in this case since the base route is actually `/user/`, `/user/:id`, and `/user/auth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the order of route definition. Move `/auth` route to `/:id` before route.

E.g.

```js
import express, { Router } from 'express';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const router = Router();
router.route('/auth').get((req, res) => {
  res.send('auth');
});
router.route('/:id').get((req, res) => {
  res.send({ id: req.params.id });
});

app.use('/user', router);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:${port}`));
```

Test and output:

```
 ⚡  curl http://localhost:3000/user/auth
auth%                                 
 ⚡  curl http://localhost:3000/user/123 
{"id":"123"}%
```